# Route with out parameter works fine, but with parameter view is not working properly in Laravel 5

Tags: view, routes, laravel-5

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/viewprofile/{uid?}','userController@viewprofile');
```

---

**userController.php**

```
public function viewprofile($uid){
        if ($uid <> NULL)
        {
           $getUser = User::where('id','=',$uid)->first();
            return View('user.profile')->with('getUser',$getUser);
        }
    }
```

---

**inbox.blade.php**

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('viewprofile',[$msg->user->id]) }}"> {{$msg->user->username }} </a>
```

---

when I use route parameter **profile.blade.php** page design collapses, but when I use simple route `Route::get('/viewprofile','userController@viewprofile');` 
it works fine. Need help! thanks in advance.

Comment: So what happens if you navigate to `/viewprofile/1` or `/viewprofile/`? Both cases fail? Can you `dd($getUser)` before `return` and put the result here when you navigate to `/viewprofile/123123`? Have you considered what happens if user with a given `uid` doesn't exist?

Comment: `dd($getUser)` shows `null` when I navigate to `viewprofile/123123` and uid=123123 doesn't exists 
am I doing anything wrong with route-parameter? @CrakingTheCode

Comment: I think the problem is with how you treat `$getUser` object. But before that what happens if you use this in your inbox instead: `<a href="{{ url('/viewprofile/'.$msg->user->id) }}"> {{$msg->user->username }} </a>` does it still fail? This should work in Laravel 5.

Comment: still its not working.. anyway thnx for concern @CrackingTheCode